# backgrid filter, custom template?

Tags: javascript, backgrid

I am trying to change the of Backgrid.Extension.ClientSideFilter

```
template: _.template('<div class="input-prepend input-append"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span><input type="text" <% if (placeholder) { %> placeholder="<%- placeholder %>" <% } %> name="<%- name %>" /><span class="add-on"><a class="close" href="#">&times;</a></span><span class="add-on"><div class="red" id="<%- idDivCantidadResultados %>"></div></span></div>'),
```

but i don't know how to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put it into the constructor.

```
var filter = new Backgrid.Extension.ClientSideFilter({
  template: _.template("<...>",  /* Underscore template context */ {foo: bar}),
  collection: collection,
  fields: ['field']
});
```

http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: I'm also trying to customize the filter, and I can't make it work based on these instructions. I'm getting the default filter regardless of what custom template I've specified in the constructor. Any gotchas I may be falling into?

Comment: @raddevon no but if u could reproduce it, it could be a bug, and u should file a bug report

Comment: I just found out that, in older versions of backgrid filter, you could not pass a new template into the constructor. You have to sub-class the filter class in order to customize the template. It's only been in a recent update that it looks for a template in the constructor.